# How to solve this thread blocking issue

Tags: java, multithreading, blocking

I'm testing a Java multi-threading sample code but the thread started in the for loop of qB.start() is blocked because it's waiting for entry of qB monitor. What is the cause of this blockage?

Thank you.

```
import java.util.*;

class QA {

public synchronized void open() throws Exception {

    Thread o = new Thread() {

        public void run() {

            QB qB = new QB();

            qB.start();
        }
    };

    o.start();
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    new QA().open();
}

public class QB {

private boolean shutdown;
private Vector<Thread> tList;
private final Object waitingLock = new Object();

public QB() {

    tList = new Vector<Thread>();
}

public synchronized void start() {


    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

        final int id = i;

        Thread t = new Thread("Thread " + id) {

            public void run() {

                load(id);
            }
        };

        tList.add(i, t);

        t.start();

    }

    tMonitor();
    waitUntilFinished();
}

private void tMonitor() {

    Thread cmt = new Thread("T Monitor Thread") {

        public void run() {

            synchronized(waitingLock) {

                while(tList.size() > 0) {

                    try {

                        sleep(10000);

                    } catch(Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                waitingLock.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    };

    cmt.start();
}

private void waitUntilFinished() {

    synchronized(waitingLock) {

        while(!isShutDown()) {

            try {


                waitingLock.wait();


            } catch(Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

private synchronized void load(int id) {

    try {

        System.out.println("blocked here");

// some work done here

removeFromTList(id);


    } catch(Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public synchronized boolean isShutDown() {

    return shutdown;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code for `removeFromTList` again @john.

Comment: public synchronized void removeFromTList(int pos) {
      tList.removeElementAt(pos);
    }

Comment: Yeah, that code has problems.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem I see is that `QB#start()` is synchronized on the instance of `QB`.
Inside the thread `t` that you are trying to spawn, `load(id)` is also synchronized on the same instance of `QB`. So when you call `t.start()` the `t` thread blocks until `QB#start()` finishes.

Presumably, at the end of the `QB#start()` method, `QB#waitUntilFinished()` is supposed to wait for all the `t` threads to finish, but they can't even enter the `QB#load` method because they're still waiting for the `QB#start()` method to release the lock on the `QB` instance.

So, circular deadlock.

Comment: Good one.  I was concentrating on the other 4 bugs and missing code.

Comment: What is the best way that you think I can use to solve this issue?

Comment: Follow the rule of thumb of doing as little as possible inside `synchronizes` blocks. So in your case, you could synchronize all the `tList` operations on `tList` instead of using `synchronized` methods, since `tList` is your only shared resource.

Comment: `tList` is already a synchronized `Vector` @john so I see little reasons for any synchronization before the `load()` method.

Comment: @Gray you're right, I forgot that `Vector` is thread-safe, I'm used to always using collections.

Comment: Agreed.  @john a `Collections.synchronizedCollection(new ArrayList())` would be better than a `Vector`.

Comment: @john Also it wouldn't hurt to make `shutdown` a `volatile` member.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

Ok, now that we see how the threads are removed from `tList` the bug is fully revealed.

If the index 0 thread finishes first then it will remove itself from the list.  That means when the index 1 thread finishes, it will remove the 1th position from the `Vector` but that does not point to itself anymore.  It is removing the #2 thread.  Sooner or later you are going to get an exception when the remove happens because it is going to be removing an invalid index.

You need to remove items from the `Vector` by address and not by position:

```
 tList.remove(this);
```

That will remove the current thread from the list.  You should also just do an `add(t)` instead of an `add(i t)` in the start loop:

```
 tList.add(t);
```

You now don't need the id position passed into your thread at all.

---

I don't see where you are removing the finished threads from your `tList`.  I see a definition (not that you edited your OP) of a `removeFromTList()` method but I don't see it used anywhere.  In `tMonitor` you are in a while loop here:

```
        while(tList.size() > 0) {
            try {
                sleep(10000);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // you never get to this line 
        waitingLock.notifyAll();
```

But I don't see anything that removes the thread from the list.  Maybe when the threads each finish they are supposed to remove themselves?

If `tMonitor` thread never gets out of that loop then it never calls:

```
waitingLock.notifyAll();
```

So the main thread will hang forever in `waitUntilFinished();`.

```
synchronized(waitingLock) {
    while(!isShutDown()) {
        try {
            waitingLock.wait();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Also, you don't want to do a `sleep` in `tMonitor()` because you are in a `synchronized` block.  You should be doing a:

```
  waitingLock.wait(10000);
```

Nothing will ever notify it but it's bad form to hold the lock like that in a sleep.

Comment: Sorry I left that part out I have included the part but the issue still remains.

Comment: Where do you call `removeFromTlist` @john?